# Flutter blocTest Missing type arguments for generic function 'blocTest<B extends BlocBase<State>, State>'

Tags: flutter, bloc, bloc-test

When following the bloc test [documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/testing), I created the following `blocTest`;

```
blocTest('should do something',
    build: () => SignInBloc(signIn: mockSignIn),
    act: (bloc) => bloc.add(const OnEmailChanged(email: 'test')));
```

However I get the intellisense error;

```
Missing type arguments for generic function 'blocTest<B extends BlocBase<State>, State>'.
```

And the `(bloc)` provided in the `add` is of type `Object?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue you have to tell the blocTest what types to expect.

```
blocTest<SignInBloc, SignInState>('should do something',
    build: () => SignInBloc(signIn: mockSignIn),
    act: (bloc) => bloc.add(const OnEmailChanged(email: 'test')));
  });
```